# How to call an action that return dispatch function using React Hook?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk

I am using React Class and Hooks both. I know I should not but you know how company's legacy code works. We are going towards hook but it will take times and effort. We are using redux thunk. At pagination to render users, we have action like:

action.js file:

```
export const fetchAccounts = (page, countPerPage)=>{
  return function (dispatch){
    dispatch(fetchAccountsInit());
    return axiosInstance.get(`/auth/users/fetch-users/${page}/${countPerPage}`)
     .then(res => res.data)
     .then(accounts=>{
         dispatch(fetchAccountsSuccess(accounts));
         return accounts
      })
     .catch(({response}) => {
     dispatch(fetchAccountsFail(response.data.errors));
  })
```

}
}

The previous developer did as:
User.js File which is using hook:

```
const getUserList = () => {    
  dispatch(actions.fetchAccounts(page, countPerPage))
  .then(res => {  
      setUsers(res);
      setCountPerPage(10);
      setTotalRows(res[0].total_count);
  }).catch(err => {
    setUsers({});
  });
}

useEffect(() => {
  getUserList();
}, [page]);
```

The code is running with no issue. But to me it seems like it is not right. I believe the code should be as:

```
export const fetchAccounts = (page, countPerPage)=>{
  return function (dispatch){
     dispatch(fetchAccountsInit());
     axiosInstance.get(`/auth/users/fetch-users/${page}/${countPerPage}`)
       .then(res => res.data)
       .then(accounts=>dispatch(fetchAccountsSuccess(accounts)))
       .catch(({response}) => {
           dispatch(fetchAccountsFail(response.data.errors));
       })
  }
}
```

When I call `const getUserList = () => { ...` the same function above
I get error as `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

There is no mapDispatchToProps in the User.js file which is working now. It is using `import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';` and `const dispatch = useDispatch();` I think I am not understanding how this pagination should work if change the action. The code in this project that I am working is this right or it has some issue?

Answer (score 0):

Before your change, the thunk was returning a promise of the final data - you removed that `return` and now it returns `undefined`. If you want to do a `dispatch(thunk()).then(...)`, that thunk still has to return a promise.

Comment: So what is the way to call the dispatch function inside "const getUserList()" after changing the action so that I can chain "then." Should I call as `dispatch(thunk(actions.fetchAccounts(page, countPerPage))).then(...)`

Comment: Yes, that would be possible.